# Use function to set default value in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, grafana, node-red

I've just started to put my firs steps into DB world. The task is to take some data from existing DB, manipulate it a bit and put results into newly created DB. Later I'm planning to make a Grafana dashboard from a data in the new DB.

I've already created some flows in node-red which are being injected one by one. This means that I have just one new value of just one column at any current timestamp. Rest is filled with 0, NULL or any other default values.

The thing is that when I create a Grafana table it looks like some random spikes between zeros.

*So the question is this:* I am looking for a way to somehow "freeze" in DB the last value of any column > 0.

In other words I'm looking for a way to SET DEFAULT as a function, which if the new value is 0 or null would go back, check the last value of any column > 0 and insert it instead of O or NULL.

Hope I was clear enough and thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: Impossible. When DEFAULT value uses any function it may operate with column values belongs current record only, not over the whole table. You may use trigger logic, of course but you may easily to calculate "last above not-zero value" in a query. And this is better, because it does not alter source data.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please elaborate on how I can calculate "last above not-zero value"?

Comment: For example, it may be correlated query with proper filtering condition (value > 0), ordering (datetime?) and limitation.

Comment: [small example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d70f4335805e6aef13c5ce2ba49fa7a1)

Comment: It's worked, thank you :)